An algorithm for sorting puzzle game
Game example
Game behaviour 
I am making a sorting puzzle game.
Game logic:
There is 3 stacks with nuts and 1 extra empty stack.
To win, player needs to put all nuts of same colour on steak.
Rules of game:
Only the top nut of each stack can be moved.
A nut can be moved on top of another nut of the same colour
A nut can be moved in an empty stack.
For my project, I have assigned each stack a one coloured nuts. Then, I randomly shuffled them between all stacks. After some tests, 4 out of 12 levels were unresolvable. There were just no possible moves.
Current code:
private void ShuffleChips(List<Column> columns)
{
    List<ChipData> allChipData = new List<ChipData>();

    foreach (Column column in columns)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < column.Chips.Count - 1; i++)
        {
            allChipData.Add(column.Chips[i].Data);
        }
    }

    allChipData = allChipData.OrderBy(_ => Random.value).ToList();

    int dataIdx = 0;
    foreach (Column column in columns)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < column.Chips.Count - 1; i++)
        {
            column.Chips[i].Assign(allChipData[dataIdx++]);
        }
    }
}

Visualization image description here
So, the question is in shuffling.
What algorithms can I use to make sure level is 100% solvable?

What you can do is go backward from a valid end solution and do N random moves from this position. Keep in mind that you cannot use your normal regular moves here since the origin of a nut could be from a stack where the second top nut is of a different color. However, this makes it even easier to find a valid "back" move as you only need to check if the stack is free for a nut to move. When you do such N "back" moves and record the sequence, you also build an actual valid sequence to solve the puzzle you just created.

How can there be no possible moves? With 3 colors and 4 non-empty stacks, there are always 2 stacks with the same color on top, so we can move all nuts of this color from the top of one stack to another. This either decreases the number of pairs of adjacent nuts with different colors, or adds an empty stack which we can use to do the same thing.

In the actual game at least, the stacks have a max size
